# Unity VRTK (basic) can't change default meshes

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

Doing the UnityVRTK beginner tutorial so sorry for such a basic questions but every time it says to change a default mesh to one created for the project I get an error telling me it needs to be unlocked and the project mesh (or shader when working with shaders) does not come in the list. Sometimes I can drag it in to the inspector but usually it's not an option and everything is shaded gray and I can't change it. How do I unlock?